# How can access the angular5 httpclient answer?

Tags: httpclient, angular5

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

userObservable: any = {};

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit(): void {

```
this.httpClient.get<UserResponse>("http://localhost:9000/home")
    .subscribe(data  => {console.log(data.status);
                         console.log(data.password);
                         this.userObservable = data;
                         console.log('Result ==> ',this.userObservable);
                        },
               error => {}
);
console.log(this.userObservable);
```

}

when the last console statement is executed, the displayed value is null. I need to manipulate the httpclient answer in other components of my application. how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

It is because your last console.log() statement fire before you get your http answer. What I would suggest is to use a service:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.getUserData().subscribe(data => {
      console.log("Data :", data, "Data from service :", this.userService.userObservable);
      // DO OTHER STUFF
    });
  }


}

// Service
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
@Injectable()
  export class UserService {
     userObservable: any = {};

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

    getUserData() {
    this.httpClient.get<UserResponse>("http://localhost:9000/home").subscribe(
      data => {
        this.userObservable = data;
        console.log("Result ==> ", this.userObservable);
        return data;
      },
      error => {
        return error;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

You will be able to get your userData in every component using the service.